# Enviar email com tamplate codeigniter

Tags: codeigniter

Olá pessoal da comunidade, eu sou estagiário em uma empresa de programação, e agora estou tentando enviar um email com tamplate usando o  codeigniter, vcs poderiam me ajudar, já consegui enviar o email, o problema é que não consigo enviar os dados na view que deve carregalos, vcs podem me ajudar?

Answer (score 1):

Uma forma de enviar email a partir de template html é usando a classe parser do CI da seguinte forma:

1° Criando uma view, onde ele será a página a ser enviada por email:

```
<html>
<body>
<h3>{seu_nome}</h3>
<p>{mensagem}</p>
</body>
</html>
```

2° No método no controller implementado basicamente da seguinte forma:

```
//Carregar biblioteca
$this->load->library('parser');

//Dados a serem renderizados na página de envio.
$data = array(
  'seu_nome' => 'João da silva',
  'mensagem' => 'Minha mensagem',
);

//Gerar página html e retorna-lá a variável $pagina
$pagina = $this->parser->parse('name_view_template', $data, true);
```

Answer (score 0):

Na realidade não é dificil, tentando aqui consegui

```
 $message = $this->load->view('pasta/pagina', $data, true);

 $this->email->message($message);
 $this->email->send();
```

basta passar os dados para view

obg.